# How to run server as part of test?

Tags: scala, sbt, spray, typesafe-activator

I'm writing a simple REST API using [spray](http://spray.io), and as part of it, I'd like to be able to set up a database with mock data, then spin up the REST server using that test database.

The problem is that I don't really know how I should go about spinning up a test instance to be up and running to execute tests against. Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between tests and the production code from sbt's point of view is mostly the location of the code. It's driven by [the configuration scope facility in sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Scopes.html#Scoping+by+configuration+axis):

> A configuration defines a flavor of build, potentially with its own classpath, sources, generated packages, etc. The configuration concept comes from Ivy, which sbt uses for managed dependencies Library Dependencies, and from MavenScopes.

What you can do in `Compile` scope should be easily applicable to `Test` and vice versa. It may or may not be as easy as it sounds, but there should not be that many hoops along the way.

[As I pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588738/how-can-i-run-a-server-with-sbt-as-a-test#comment43635112_27589095), when you do `sbt run` it's as if you did `sbt compile:run`...well, almost, but you can assume, it does. Configure the test instance of your database and server, and execute them all with `sbt test:run` or even better - write a test, possibly an integration test, that's going to do all what's needed as part of its run and give it a run with `sbt it:test` - see [Integration Tests](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html#Integration+Tests).

Answer (score 1):

You can add an object to /src/test. This object will bootstrap your server just as it would normally, with the exception that you use a mock database.

If you do not identify this object as a test class, then it will not interfere with your test suite. This is depended on the test system you are using.

For example, in Spec2 it will automatically run any test class that extends Specification. If you do not extend this class, then it will not be run.

Additional segregation on package level may be wise.

Comment: I tried something like this, "object TestSperver extends App", but when I tried "sbt run" it didn't appear as one of the classes I could execute. What would I need to do to run it?

See: https://github.com/ririw/circusoc-backend/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/circusoc/TestTest.scala

Comment: You'd have to execute `sbt test:run`.